# Query `pg_stat_database` view through sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to access `pg_stat_database` view through sqlalchemy metadata, but its throwing error. Here is my code

```
engine = "Some_engine_specification"
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, views=True, only=["table", "table2", "pg_stat_database"]
base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
base.prepare()
```

It throws error saying it cannot reflect `pg_stat_database`.

Even if I dont specify the `only=['blablabla']` part, it still give error while initialising the class as

```
pg_stats = base.classes.pg_stat_database
```

Even if i mention the scheme, still the error. I am able to access other tables by above code though.

**Edit 1**

Thanks to Ilja Everilä. To correctly reflect and get the instance of the table, use following:

```
engine = "some_engine_specification"
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=["table1", "table2"])
metadata.reflect(engine, schema='pg_catalog', views=True, only=["pg_stat_database"]
base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
base.prepare()
table1 = base.classes.table1
table2 = base.classes.table2
pg_stat_database = base.metadata.sorted_tables[index_of_pg_stat_database]
# To query
result = scoped_db_session.query(pg_stat_database).filter(pg_stat_database.columns.datname=="your_database")
```

Comment: How can you get the correct index programmatically?

Comment: you mean `index_of_pg_stat_database`?

Comment: Yes. I guess if you just combine your lists that you pass to `only`, sort them and then do an index of? Feels dirty.

Comment: I cant verify this on my side as of now, but may be there is some unique key withing `pg_stat_database`, `sorted_tables`. loop over them and stop when you find the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to automap the view as a model because there is no primary key:

> ... then, each **viable** Table within the MetaData will get a new mapped class generated automatically.

and

> **Note**
>
> By **viable**, we mean that for a table to be mapped, it must specify a primary key. Additionally, if the table is detected as being a pure association table between two other tables, it will not be directly mapped and will instead be configured as a many-to-many table between the mappings for the two referring tables.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use

Reflecting it as a table through meta is possible though. Your current expression is just looking in the wrong place. You have to explicitly pass it the correct [schema](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect.params.schema):

```
# Reflect from schema "pg_catalog"
metadata.reflect(engine, views=True, schema="pg_catalog",
                 only=["pg_stat_database"])
# Reflect from the default schema of this meta, if any
metadata.reflect(engine, only=["table", "table2"])
```

Comment: no more errors in `metadata.reflect`, now how do I get the instance og `pg_stats_database`? `base.classes.pg_stat_database` is throwing error. I can see it in `base.metadata.sorted_tables[2].pg_catalog.pg_stat.database`, but thats too long.

Comment: You cannot create a mapped class for the view in question, as there are no primary keys, so it cannot be accessed through `base.classes`. Your only option is to use the table. Just assign it to a shorter name: `pg_stat_database = metadata.tables['pg_catalog.pg_stat_database']` and use that.